# Mojave freezes for a split second around every 25 seconds when there is a second user logged in

Tags: mojave, performance

My MacBook Pro 2016 touch bar with Mojave freezes for a split second every 20~30 seconds when there is another user logged in.

But the other account logged in does not have any apps or suspicious processes running. Console.app shows nothing relevant during the tiny freeze.

I see a lot of users complaining about cursor freezing every time but with my laptop the entire screen, keyboard, and mouse freezes.

I don't use a second monitor or any other accessory - just the laptop using the touchpad as a mouse, not an external mouse.

The problem does not occur with only one user logged in.

Is there any clue about this problem?

Comment: do you mean logged in remotely through ssh and/or screen sharing? Or just having logged in and switched user without logging out

Comment: @user3052786 just having logged in and switched user without logging out.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you test creating a new user account and seeing if the problem happens with it as well? You could narrow down possible suspects, not a lot to go on atm.

Comment: @user3052786 I have created a new user, restarted the laptop to "clean" the memory, I logged in with this new user, and didn't open anything and then switched to my account. Thats when MacOS starts to freeze. Afterwards, I went back to the test user, without logging out of my own account, and logged off. Finally I got back to my usual account, and the laptop stopped freezing.
This basically sums up the procedures.

Comment: How about when you boot in safe mode? Hold shift on startup to do this or add `-x` flag to the boot arguments before restart, e.g. `sudo nvram boot-args="-x"`.

Comment: @user3052786 I can't switch account while in recovery mode. The loading icon never ends at login screen while switching users. I'm afraid I will have to format my Mac :/

Comment: I'd probably do the same thing at this point.. Wiping the drive and reinstalling should fix the problem (if it doesn't, might be a hardware issue) but when you put your stuff back, you could watch for the problem to return, so you can narrow down what app/driver/something else you install causes it.